# router not found error in ui-router angularjs with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have included ui-router.js for angularjs  . But somehow i am not getting it to work with requirejs.

```
require.config
baseUrl:"/Scripts/app"
paths :
    jquery      :   "libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3"
    bootstrap   :   "libs/bootstrap/bootstrap"
    angular     :   "libs/angular/angular"
    domReady    :   "libs/requirejs/domReady"
    blockui     :   "libs/jquery.blockUI"
    "ui-router" :   "libs/angular/angular-ui-router"
    "angular-resource"  :   "libs/angular/angular-resource"

shim:
    jquery:
        exports:
            "jquery"

    bootstrap:
        depts:["jquery"]

    angular:
        exports:
            "angular"

    "ui-router":
        exports:
            "ui.router"
        deps : ['angular']

    blockui : 
        deps : ["jquery"]

        "angular-resource":
            deps: ['angular']

    deps :['app','utils/common']

require ['angular','jquery','bootstrap','routes'] ,(angular,$) ->   
    $(document).ready ->
        angular.bootstrap document,['app']
```

now my app.coffee is

```
define ['angular','angular-resource','ui-router'] , (angular) ->
angular.module 'app',['ngResource']
```

the console gives error in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
```

and

```
  TypeError: g is undefined    
g = g[part];
```

in firefox . Why am I not able to use ui-router as my module to load it into my modules for route.coffee ?

Answer (score 2):

finally got the answer from this guy in ui-router project here is the answer link

[Ui-Router Issue for requirejs load with AMD](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/479)

Answer (score 0):

```
"ui-router":
    exports:
        "ui.router"
    deps : ['angular']
```

especially `"ui.router"` is the bad guy here.

solution: don't use the dot in its name.
i used "uiRouter" even for the export!

Comment: I already did that . But somehow its telling `Cannot read property 'router' of undefined` in require.js

Comment: It worked for me: ```  uiRouter: {
   deps: ["angular", "ngRoute"],```

Answer (score 0):

if the module name is incorrect, requirejs can't load the script file. so your can't get the router.
in development environment, you should open the console window, in this window, you should find the error from requirejs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: first, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/562171/joy) use define of requirejs to load the ui-router, this is ok, but, not

Comment: requirejs, angularjs have two module management system.  first, in app.js, [joy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/562171/joy) use define of requirejs to load the ui-router, this is ok, but, not use angular.module to attach ui-router to current module. then, ui.router not a good name.

Comment: in app.js, you should use 
    angular.module( 'app',['ui.router'] )
to attach the ui-router module.